# count the number of ways to partition a grid

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, discrete-geometry

In a 10x10 grid, there are 100 cells. A partition in this grid is a contiguous collection of cells meaning any two cells of a partition are connected through a path of cells in the partition itself. In how many ways can 5 partitions be created in this grid? Needless to say this can be generalized. Suggesting simpler variants and their solutions are also helpful.

A simple variant is when all partitions must share at least one cell on the boundary. No overlapping is allowed also. The partitions should add up to cover the entire grid. Each partition may have any non-zero number of cells.

Suggestion of an algorithm however computationally inefficient so that counting is done by computer would also be good if a mathematical technique is difficult to come by.

Comment: Do you have any idea how many partitions there are in a $10\times10$ grid? I bet it's an absolutely huge number, and probably has never been calculated. So I think you're asking a very hard question. Even counting the partitions in a $3\times3$ grid seems challenging.

Comment: i suggested a simpler variant.

Comment: What have you tried? Why not work with a 2x2, then 3x3, etc., and develop some methods, and then try to treat the 10x10 case?

Comment: It seems to me that [polyominoes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyomino) are relevant here. The number of ways that $5$ polyominoes can fit into a $10$ x $10$ square would give the answer.

Comment: @MatthewConroy i myself was toying with the idea of recursion.There are n ways of 2-partitions for n cells. Now this can easily be used as base case to solve any problem. In theory this seems trivial. But i could not figure out further generalization?

Comment: In the "simple variant", partitions must overlap?

Comment: No overlapping, i overlooked.

Comment: Are there any further restrictions? Do the 5 parts together make up the whole 100 cells? Do the 5 parts have to have the same number of cells?

Comment: @JaapScherphuis After you pointed out, i made the changes above and addressed these.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson: The number of partitions for a $10$ x $10$ square has actually been calculated, but only just. It is the last number in the OEIS sequence [here](https://oeis.org/A145835).

Comment: I made an algorithm which generates all possible partitions of an $n$ x $n$ grid. Thus, for $n=3$ the number of $5$-partitions is 395. For $n=4$ the number of $5$-partitions is 183,945. Unfortunately, the total number of partitions for any $n$ is roughly $10^{n-1}$ greater than the number of partitions for $n-1$. Same goes for my algorithm. I thus estimate 3 days to compute all partitions of a $5$ x $5$ grid. For a $10$ x $10$ grid, it would still be computing at the end of the Universe.

Comment: @Jens Is there a formal way to prove NP hardness of this problem?

Comment: I don't know enough about NP hardness to say. If you look at the link I gave above to the OEIS sequence, a Frank Simon was able to calculate total partitions for $n = 10$, so he clearly found a vastly better algorithm than I did.

Comment: @Jens How does one prove that "the total number of partitions for any `n` is roughly `10^{n−1}` greater than the number of partitions for `n−1`"